# Visualize Zipf's Law

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation

I want to visualize [`Zipf's Law`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)

> Zipf's law states that the frequency of a word is **inversely** proportional to its
>   rank

I tried:

```
text = ExampleData[{"Text", "DonQuixoteIEnglish"}];
count=WordCount@text;
association= WordCounts[text]
value = Take[Values@associationEnglish, 10]
frequency=value/count

ListPlot[{frequency, Table[1/rank,{rank,1,1000}] }]
```

I expected same plot but ...

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a number of problems with your code. In one place you use `WordCount`, in another `WordCounts`, and `associationEnglish` is not defined. Please edit your post with code that other people can run.  However, I suspect your issue is that you want to do this instead: `ListPlot[Transpose[{frequency, Table[1/rank,{rank,1,1000}] }]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get text:

```
textEnglish = ExampleData[{"Text", "DonQuixoteIEnglish"}];
```

Get `WordCounts`:

```
countsEnglish = Take[Values@WordCounts[textEnglish], 1000];
```

The slope of this line is ~1, so the law holds

```
f[x_] = Fit[Log[Transpose[{Range[1000], countsEnglish}]], {1, x}, x]
```

> Out[]= 10.449 - 1.08398 x

Visualize:

```
Show[
    ListLogLogPlot[countsEnglish,
        PlotStyle->PointSize[0.02],PlotTheme->"Detailed"],
    LogLogPlot[Exp[f[Log[x]]],{x,1,1000},
        PlotStyle->Directive[DotDashed,Red]],
AspectRatio->1,PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand mathematics behind Zipf's Law. why do we need log log, and then Exp[f[Log[x]]] ?  "Zipf's law states that the frequency of a word is inversely proportional to its rank" : is it correct definition of Zipf's Law ?

Comment: @vito you need log log to fit easier with a line, not a curve. You need `Exp[f[Log[x]]]` (going back from log log) to plot on a nice log-grid plot. Yes that is a good formulation, but there are more precise ones, search the web. Please except the answer if you think it is correct.